# extjs4 server side validation,how to?

Tags: c#, forms, validation, extjs4, server-side

i have a form in extjs and i need to do some validation tests on it on server side and return a message error 
but i have no clue how to do this!

i need to verify if the new added ip adress already exists

i also need to verify if it is actually a valid adress (i have a c# function that can do this)

if these conditions are ok it can be added.
if not, i'd like to show an error message to the user saying what is the problem

now when i call my save button submit,i do these tests on my c# before i do the insert query, but even if those tests arent ok it still say success on the form because i dont know how to tell extjs4 there is an error

**edit**
this is what im trying to do up to now

my form submit:

```
this.up('form').getForm().submit
({
    url: 'AddData.ashx',
    params: { action: 'addip' },
    success: function (form, action) {
        Ext.MessageBox.show({ title: 'Success !',
            msg: 'IP added successfully<br />',
            icon: Ext.MessageBox.INFO,
            buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK
        });

        Ext.getCmp('addipform').getForm().reset();
    },
    failure: function (form, action) {
        switch (action.failureType) {
            case Ext.form.action.Action.CLIENT_INVALID:
                Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', 'Form fields may not be submitted with invalid values');
                break;
            case Ext.form.action.Action.CONNECT_FAILURE:
                Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', 'Ajax communication failed');
                break;
            case Ext.form.action.Action.SERVER_INVALID:
                Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', action.result.msg);
        }
    }
})
```

inside my AddData.ashx there is a function  addip() which get called when   action param is 'addip'
this function return :

```
public string addip()
{
   //my queries ...
   string result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize("{    success:false,  errors:{    text:\"The IP already exist!\",  ip:\"The is not an IP !\"  }  }");
   return result;
}
```

but nothing happens!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are submitting your form to C#, once you have performed the validations and if those validations fail, then you will have to output JSON in following format:

```
{
    success:false,
    errors:{
        field1:errorMsg1,
        field2:errorMsg2
    }
}
```

Here, field1 is the name of the field present in your form at which you want to display the error.

You will have to output this JSON from your server side, the way you do when you respond to an Ajax request and this will itself mark the required field as invalid and show the errror message on mouse over of field.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ok so if i got it right.. i submit my for to c# with an action param,then the function i need is called ,it return a string with format as u showed (with fiild1 matches the name property of the form field right?)  then i serilize it to get json. the problem is that nothing happens. can u please give me a full example,ty

Comment: Are you able to see the JSON received from server in the response body? Is there any error which you are getting to see? Check that where is your response landing to - in success or in failure function of form submission?

Comment: there is no error, in the adddata.ashx i dont see any response, i get success message and ip added to db

Comment: I guess your JSON is not being sent as an output. When you call function addip, then it returns the result, but then are you not printing this output? You will have to print this JSON (that is output it) so that it can be used at the client side. Also, are you using any tool like Firebug for checking the requests response?

Comment: ok i added Console.WriteLine(result). still nothing.
im using chrome developpement tools

Comment: i noticed something..invalid-line.gif is loaded

Comment: There seems to be an issue with your server side code. I shall advise you to debug it because as you say - " i dont see any response, i get success message and ip added to db" - if the validation is failing then how is it getting added? As for ExtJs, the fields will be marked as invalid once you output the JSON in the format shared above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4575/discussion-between-astrocybernaute-and-netemp)

Comment: this is my json  
"{ success:false, errors:{ ip: \"Failure : Bad Ip address \" }}"

Answer (score 1):

Before you have it up and running, please make sure you already have pages that can serve the queries similar to these calls:

```
Request: http://localhost/verify.aspx?ip=192.168.0.1
Response: {success: true, message: "The IP is correct"} //you can pass as much items as you want here

Request: http://localhost/verify.aspx?ip=127.0.0.1
Response: {success: false, message: "The IP is already exist!"}
```

That sounds simple right?

Then in your ExtJS, you can have code like this (Pardon if there is any syntax error, haven't test it yet)

```
var w = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    width: 300,
    height: 250,
    items: Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'IP'
        }]
    }),
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Save',
        handler: function() {
            var ip = w.down('textfield').getValue();

            //Some client side validation first
            //then we submit it

            //Use Ajax request          
            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: 'http://localhost/verify.aspx?ip='+ip,
                success: function(r) {

                    //r is the raw response object, we need to parse it
                    var res = Ext.decode(r.responseText, true);

                    //Then here we are. We can check the transaction
                    //status. This is the exact object you passed
                    //in the above Request-Response pair.
                    if (res.success) {
                        //ip is correct. Do your other stuff here
                    }else{
                        //ip is incorrect. You may want to show the error message
                        alert(res.message);
                    }

                }
            }); 
        }
    }]
});
```

*Disclaimer: This is just a simple example, I hope it helps :)*

Comment: thank you so much for ur reply. I tried to make this works but it seems i cant even do ur pre-requests ! i can do my queries and get a response like u said, but i dont know how to send it back to extjs so it can be accessed via success: function(r) :(

Comment: You don't need to explicitly send the request back to Extjs. What you need to do is to make sure your server can manage to print the json object on the screen on request. When your Ajax do the request, it will automatically builds the connection and read whatever is printed on the response page. Hope it's clear :)